# how to supply universal-argument (C-u) to a function call inside a binding statement

Tags: key-bindings, magit, evil

I have this on my init.el

```
;; magit status
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "gs" 'magit-status)
```

But I would like to have another binding, for `C-u M-x magit-status` (C-u is the universal-argument)

Something like (which obviously does not work):

```
;; magit status
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "ga" 'C-u magit-status)
```

*rationale*: with `C-u M-x magit-status`, magit allows you to supply a directory where a git repo resides, so you do not have to have an opened file that resides inside the git repo where you want to perform git actions.

Comment: This question has been asked numerous times. Finding all the duplicates might not be so easy, but is probably worth doing, if someone has the time. The dup I pointed to provides the answer as essentially (for this question) `(define-key evil-motion-state-map "ga" (lambda (interactive) (let ((current-prefix-arg 4)) (call-interactively 'magit-status))))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#'magit-status` is fun, because its argument to `interactive` isn't just a string, so running it naively with `call-interactively` doesn't work.Instead, the function generates its own interactive arguments. Here's the `interactive` call inside `(defun magit-status ...`:

```
(interactive
 (list (and (or current-prefix-arg (not (magit-toplevel)))
            (magit-read-repository
             (>= (prefix-numeric-value current-prefix-arg) 16)))))
```

So we have to bind `current-prefix-arg` directly, to pretend it's been called with a prefix arg:

```
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "ga"
 (lambda () (interactive)
   (let ((current-prefix-arg 4))
     (call-interactively #'magit-status))))
```

Or, as I tested it (because I don't use evil-mode):

```
(global-set-key
 (kbd "C-c C-s")
 (lambda () (interactive)
   (let ((current-prefix-arg 4))
     (call-interactively #'magit-status))))
```

Thanks to @npostavs for the instruction on binding `current-prefix-arg`. The previous answer (for the purposes of transparency) was:

```
(global-set-key
 (kbd "C-c C-s")
 (lambda () (interactive)
   (magit-status (magit-read-repository
                  (>= (prefix-numeric-value current-prefix-arg) 16)))))
```

Comment: tks. How would you do it using `call-interactively`? (just so I can test it).

Comment: "running it with call-interactively doesn't work" - it works for me, did you try it?

Comment: @ninrod what did you want to use `call-interactively` for that binding it doesn't test?

Comment: @npostavs I did try it. I don't see a way to pass a universal argument to it. So it does not do the desired behavior for the question, but runs magit-status on the current directory (if it's a git repo). I can only find ways to `call-interactively` it so it does *not* get a universal argument.

Comment: Oh, I see, in that case just let-bind `current-prefix-arg` (note that this is not really related to using a string or lisp form as the argument to `interactive`).

Comment: @zck, I wanted to test the `naive` way you mentioned: "so running it naively with call-interactively doesn't work". I'm so limited in lisp that I did not know how do do something as simple as that.

Comment: "because its argument to interactive isn't just a string" - you would have the same issue with a function using `(interactive "P")`.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need a separate keybinding to pass the universal argument to the command.  Based on your current keybinding, you may simply type <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>s</kbd>.

Comment: I knew that, but really, I use this so often that I would like to bind it to another more comfortable sequence like `ga`.

Comment: suppose I wan't to know, actually, how I can bind a key sequence, like `C-x g` so that this sequence actually performs another sequence, like `C-u g s`? But i think that is a diferent question.

Comment: @ninrod: sorry, misunderstood your intent!

Answer (score 2):

Even better, if you don't want to risk doing the wrong thing when/if `magit-status` is changed:

```
(define-key evil-motion-state-map "ga"
  (lambda () (interactive)
    (universal-argument)
    (call-interactively 'magit-status))
```

or to test without using evil:

```
(global-set-key
 (kbd "C-c C-s")
 (lambda () (interactive)
   (universal-argument)
   (call-interactively 'magit-status)))
```

Basically `universal-argument` sets up the state as if you had pressed `C-u` (because `C-u` is actually bound to `universal-argument`), then the next interactively-called function reads that state. If you wanted to call a function as if `C-u` had been pressed twice, then you would first call `universal-argument` and then `universal-argument-more`. Numeric arguments could be supplied with `digit-argument` and `negative-argument`; see simple.el for the actual code that implements all of this.

Comment: I just tested and zck's solution works but your's does not. +1 anyway because I did not know how to do the universal-argument stuff. rich info here.